# How to change owner/group 48 48 to other?

Tags: php

I have a webpage to upload files.When upload a file,its `owner/group is 48 48`.I want to change it to `1036667 103667` like other files(uploaded from filezilla).So that users cannot directly view the

```
file(www.somewebsite.com/somefile.txt).
```

Comment: If you don't want visitors from your website to view them directly, restrict access with .htaccess: `Order Allow,Deny\nDeny from all`

Answer (score 0):

chmod is your friend for this.

```
syntax: chmod(file,mode)

mode    Required. Specifies the new permissions.

The mode parameter consists of four numbers:

The first number is always zero
The second number specifies permissions for the owner
The third number specifies permissions for the owner's user group
The fourth number specifies permissions for everybody else

Possible values (to set multiple permissions, add up the following numbers):

1 = execute permissions
2 = write permissions
4 = read permissions


eg:

<?php
// Read and write for owner, nothing for everybody else
chmod("test.txt",0600);

// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("test.txt",0644);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for everybody else
chmod("test.txt",0755);

// Everything for owner, read for owner's group
chmod("test.txt",0740);
?>
```

Comment: I already change the permission to chmod("test.txt",0600) after uploading a file.Even though,uploaded files can be view directly while uploaded files from filezilla can't.